# Product and Sizes symfony2 doctrine example

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to symfony2 and I'm building my first online store with it. I have products and I want to add product sizes, one product can have many sizes and one size can have many products. For example: two products cat have 'M' size.

```
class Product {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Size", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sizes")
     */
    private $sizes;
}

//in another file
class Size {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="sizes")
     */

    protected $products;
}
```

ProductController.php

```
...
            ->add('sizes', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SizeType::class,
                'label' => 'Sizes',
                'allow_add'    => true,
            ])
...
```

SizeType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Size');

    $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->getQuery();

    $sizes = $q->getResult();

    $builder->add('name', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Size',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
    ));
}
```

Right now I'm getting
`Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Size could not be converted to string` I can fix if I implement `__toString()` but I don't know if this is the right thing to do, and if I do this, when editing the product, the dropdown doesn't select the right size.

My question is, is this the right way to implement product - sizes function to online store?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
$builder->add('name', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Size',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'property' => 'needed_property_name' //just write the needed property name there
));
```

Comment: `The choice_label option was introduced in Symfony 2.7. Prior to Symfony 2.7, it was called property (which has the same functionality).` http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Comment: Oh, I see, that's my fault - forgot about this.

Comment: About selecting wrong size when editing: possibly it could be issue when you don't provide `choice_value` in the field options. From the doc: "default is null. If null is used, an incrementing integer is used as the name.". See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14825

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured out better way to do it, 'entity' type with multiple => true

```
        ->add('sizes', 'entity', [
            'class' => Size::class,
            'label' => 'Размери',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            //'allow_add'    => true,
        ])
```

This way multiple sizes can be selected, with [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) I've made it good looking and perfectly works for me now.

I'd love to hear if there is a better way.

Answer (score -2):

Product annotations looks wrong. The `JoinTable` is a lookup table for many-to-many relation:

[image: Lookup table]

The convention is to name it after linked tables: `products_sizes` in your case:

```
class Product {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Size", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_sizes")
     */
     private $sizes;
}
```